# Any handy tool to access mysql in GUI

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I would like to find a handy/free GUI tool which can let me manage/view Mysql and other databases(possibly). Any suggestions? Prefer windows platform tools, but Macosx is also OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools:
**Free tools:**

1. HeidiSQL (my favorit)
2. phpMyAdmin
3. MySQL Workbench (3 versions)

**Charged Tools:**

1. NaviCat

Answer (score 0):

You can install :

- MySQL Workbench
- phpMyAdmin
- other

Comment: what is others?

Comment: MySQL Workbench needs an Oracle account whihc is so complex to create.

Comment: MySQL Workbench, I have the CE edition. Maybe the Oracle account is not required for this one?

Answer (score 0):

As a management tool

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

As a server testing tool (PHP + apache server + mysql instance)

https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp